# Exceed PHP binary limit

Tags: php, string, binary, limit

I was trying to do some sort of XOR binary crypting algorithm in PHP and so I needed to convert large strings into binary. The problem is that PHP seems to be very limited in terms of binary calculation / storage as a string of six letters only, once converted, exceeds the PHP INT limit.

That means unpacking a big string to binary just gives a unusable number. I tried to do the string unpacking by splitting the string into packs of 4 letters and then unpacking them, but then I've got troubles with the repacking where it gives random characters instead of the original ones.

How can I do the unpacking of very long strings, and then store them either in a string (made only of 0s and 1s) or in a big array (where each value is either a 0 or 1, the key indicating the location of this bit) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the GMP library? Man page [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php)

quick test code:

```
<?php
$gmpValue1 = gmp_init("1562767628166296698262", 10); // note: using base 10 (decimal)
$gmpValue2 = gmp_init("2163623626362663286446", 10);

$gmpValue3 = gmp_xor($gmpValue1, $gmpValue2);

echo gmp_strval($gmpValue3, 10) . "\n"; // note: using base 10 (decimal)
```

Comment: No, didn't know this existed. I'm on PHP 5.5. Gonna look for tutorials then, thanks.

Comment: @Rackover any chance of an up-vote or select as answer, if this helped? :)